# Can't disable dev mode on Redux

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I've downloaded Redux from WP plugin repo. It tells me that the `dev_mode` is `on` and that I don't have the latest Redux build. I've turned `off` the `dev_mode` in `sample-config` and `barebones-config` and nothing changed.

It works, when I install the dev mode disabler plugin, but I don't want to have to ship it off to users together with the framework itself. I tried copying the code from the disabler plugin into my `functions.php` and no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Find this:

```
'dev_mode'         => true,
```

inside your default `setArguements()` function
and change the parameter to `true/false` as you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. setArguments array in options-init.php doesn't contain the dev_mode variable and I had to add it. That worked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your configation page and make `'dev_mode' => false`.

It will not exactly work if `WP_DEBUG` is `True` in your `wp-config.php` file.

If you want to disable the Developer Mood in Redux then first set the `WP_DEBUG` to `false`, then go to `config.php` ( whatever you name your configuration file ) and set `'dev_mode' => false`.